# Remove specific lines of a regex pattern targets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
ABC
5
0
gdfgdfg
-----------
GHN
3
0
ffffffff
fffff
ffff
trte
-------------
H
1
0
----------------
```

I would like to delete lines where the line above them starts with a character, and the line below them starts and ends with a zero.
for example above list must convert to following:

```
ABC

0
gdfgdfg
-----------
GHN

0
ffffffff
fffff
ffff
trte
-------------
H

0
----------------
```

following regex can select target lines **but I don't know how to remove second lines of regex**:

```
^(.+\S)$\R^(\d+)$\R^(0)$
```

**note that second lines must include only a single number between 0-9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use

```
^(.*\S\R)(\d)(\R0)$
```

Replace with `$1$3`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r0hpWr/2).

It is the same as find `^(.*\S\R)\d(\R0)$` and replace with `$1$2` but I kept the third group just in case you need it.

*Details*

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.*\S\R)` - Group 1: a line ending with a non-whitespace char and a line break (sequence)
- `(\d)` - Group 2: a digit between `0` and `9`
- `(\R0)` - Group 3: a line break (sequence) and `0`
- `$` - end of a line.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it is good but second or between lines must include a single number under 10

Comment: @PubgMobile where is this information explained in the question? What do you mean exactly? If `\d+` is supposed to only match a number from `0` to `10`, replace `\d+` with `(?:0?\d|10)` or `(?:\d|10)`.

Comment: tnq I added extra info to end of question

Comment: @PubgMobile `\d` matches any digit from `0` to `9`, so all you need is to remove `+` after `\d` in my initial regex. If you need to support a leading `0`, add `0?`, `0?\d`.

Answer (score 2):

You can start the line with a character A-Za-z.

Then match all following lines that start with a digit 1-9 (or `[0-9]` to also match zeroes) and assert a zero on the next line.

In the replacement use a newline.

```
^[A-Za-z].*\R\K(?:[1-9]\R)*(?=0$)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z].*` Match a single character A-Z (As the example data starts with `ABC` and `GHN`)
- `\R\K` Match a newline and forget what is matched so far
- `(?:\R[1-9]\R)*` Repeat 0+ lines with a single digit 1-9 and a newline
- `(?=\R0$)` Assert a newline and a single zero on the next line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltULl5/1)

For a single line and numbers 0-9:

```
^[A-Za-z].*\R\K(?:[0-9]\R)?(?=0$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q9Jxuw/1)

[image]